# 80s/90s movie where boy finds out his dad's girlfriend/second wife is actually an alien/monster

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

To be honest, I vaguely remember this one scene from the movie (I was like 5 when I saw it I think).

The scene depicts a teenager spying on this stepmom/dad's girlfriend along with a girl (possibly girlfriend) because he has a hunch something weird is up with her and he sees her in the backyard transformed into her alien form.

The movie probably belongs to the horror-scifi genre since the alien form was scary (at least to the 5 year old me).

The movie is possibly from the late 80s/early 90s.

Comment: Do any of these look familiar? [IMDB: Ultimate list of 80s 90s Sci-Fi & B-movies](https://imdb.com/list/ls076002452/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Stepmonster* (1993).

From [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0108223/):

> Todd Dougherty has an imagination driven by comic book. So when he accuses his soon-to-be stepmother of being a monster, no one believes him. When neighbors start turning up dead, it becomes a race against time for Todd to stop this hideous, carnivorous creature from marrying his dad and ruining his.

The stepmom can't tolerate the violin songs
life.

Comment: This is it! Thank you!!

Answer (score 5):

Depending on how well you remember it, this might be [*My Stepmother is an Alien*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0095687/) from 1988.  The main teenage character in that movie is a girl (Alyson Hannigan), but she hangs out with a boy (Seth Green). Her father (Dan Aykryod) is a scientist, who ends up meeting an alien (Kim Basinger).

[This review](https://www.syfy.com/syfywire/59-thoughts-we-had-while-watching-my-stepmother-is-an-alien) from SyFy wire hits most of the plot points, although in a very negative tone.

Comment: Then again, I don't think the alien in that movie had a secondary form.  And secret aliens was a fairly common 80's movie theme, so I could be way off.

Comment: Yes I don't think its this one. I already looked it up. There was a secondary form, which was scary (at least supposed to be). Don't think it was a comedy.

Comment: I'd recommend adding that (and any others that you have already eliminated) to your question.  Also, the 'not a comedy' point